# Is there a way to find rows with same column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL called `accounttransactions` storing financial transactions. Now here there are two Columns, `ref` for reference numbers and `adm` for student's admission number respectively. I want to find in this table the number of students with the same transaction number but different students bearing in mind that a student can use the same transaction number more than once.
I.E

```
---------------
| adm  | ref  |
--------------
| 102  | 2145 |
| 102  | 2145 |
| 103  | 2152 |
| 104  | 2152 |
---------------
```

for admission 102, the ref is okay. I want to find rows like admission 103 and 104.

I have tried using

```
SELECT COUNT(ref) AS num, ref FROM accounttransactions GROUP BY ref HAVING num>1
```

but this  gives me the count for the ref for all students even the ones with the same admission number

Comment: Just to confirm, What is your expected result from the above data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use correlated subquery with `exists`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=40045764d06e476a16beb1e730b075b1)**

```
select * from  accounttransactions a 
where exists 
   (select 1 from accounttransactions b where a.ref=b.ref having count(distinct adm)>1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
adm ref
103 2152
104 2152
```

Comment: This one worked just perfectly, I just had to add a group by at the end, this is the query
`select * from  accounttransactions a 
where exists 
   (SELECT 1 from accounttransactions b where a.ref=b.ref having count(distinct adm)>1)  GROUP BY ref,adm`

I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have used self join to find the output

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM accounttransactions e 
INNER JOIN accounttransactions f ON e.ref = f.ref 
WHERE e.adm != f.adm 
GROUP BY e.ref, e.adm
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `exists`, but not with aggregation:

```
select a.*
from accounttransactions a 
where exists (select 1 
              from accounttransactions a2
              where a2.ref = a.ref and
                    a2.adm <> a.adm
             );
```

With an index on `accounttransactions(ref, adm)`, this should have the best performance characteristics.